# Destructure parameter of a Clojure function while keeping the original value.

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Can you destructure a function parameter but still have the original available for use? The way I'm doing it now is just using a `let` form inside the function body, but I wondering if there was a terser way of doing it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seems like `:as` works for functions too:

with `vector`

```
(defn test [[x y :as v]]
  {:x x :y y :v v})

(test [1 2 3 4])
=>  {:x 1 :y 2 :v [1 2 3 4]}
```

with `hash-map`

```
(defn test2 [{x :x y :y :as m}]
    {:x x :y y :m m})

(test2 {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3})
=> {:x 1 :y 2 :m {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}}
```

See this terrific blog post: http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html

Comment: I believe let, fn, defn, etc. all use the same destructuring syntax.

Comment: @JohnJ That's "true".  I was very confused at the blog post at first because it only uses lets as examples.  The difference between the let and the fn/defn is that it uses a binding form.

Comment: Everything what uses `let` internally can be destructured in the same way.