# Destructuring argument in Clojure

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Newbie enjoying Clojure **a lot** here. So, I have an HTTP route:

```
 (POST   "/login"    request   (post-login request))
```

here, "request" is a map with a lot of http things inside. And the "post-login" function:

```
(defn post-login
  ;; Login into the app
  [{{email "email" password "password"} :form-params session :session :as req}]
    (let [user (modusers/get-user-by-email-and-password email password)]
     ;; If authenticated
     (if-not (nil? (:user user))
      (do
       (assoc (response/found "/")
         :session (assoc session :identity (:user user)) :flash "Bitte schön!"))
       (assoc (response/found "/login") :flash "Etwas stimmt nicht mit deinem Zugriffsprozess"))))
```

but I don't understand how "request" is being destructuring. How "email" and "password" are now available inside the function?, and what ":as req" means? Is there a name to this "technique"?

Comment: 100% of what you're asking here is covered in https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring. See "Associative Destructuring" for the map. Similarly, you can search for `:as` in that page.

Comment: ...so, insofar as `:as` is concerned, you can find an answer in [destructure parameter of a clojure function while keeping the original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575161/destructure-parameter-of-a-clojure-function-while-keeping-the-original-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's still not clear from the comments, here's a quick answer:

Your `post-login` function receives a single argument which is a map representing HTTP request. This argument is stored in `req` with the help of the special `:as` keyword.
So `(defn post-login [req] ...)` and `(defn post-login [{:as req}] ...)` are exactly the same.

A (one) way that map destructuring works is that you provide a map key on the right side and the thing to which it should be bound on the left side, e.g. `[{form-params :form-params :as req}]`. Now the `:form-params` key in `req` map will be bound to the `form-params` symbol available inside the function body.

Things get more interesting when you do "nested" destructuring. In your case, `[{{email "email" password "password"} :form-params :as req}` just means that `:form-params` key inside the request will be bound to `{email "email" password "password"}` which again is a destructuring itself. Eventually, the `"email"` key in `:form-params` will be bound to the `email` symbol and the same for `password`.
As before, if you need access to the whole request (not just some params inside it) you may get that via `:as`.

Note: there's an alternative syntax which you can use (a kind of shortcut):

`[{{:strs [email password]} :form-params session :session :as req}]`