# Specifying bindings syntax with :as

Tags: clojure

Say I have a binding such as:

`loop [[x & more :as tree] tree, minVal 99, maxVal -99]`

What does `:as` do? I have tried looking around but can't find anything about it.

Comment: This is explicitly documented in https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring; the question itself is a subset of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375198/destructuring-argument-in-clojure (I'd close it as duplicate, but arguably, the *other* question should be closed as being too-broad, cramming several questions into one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explicitly-on-point example in https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring --

> ```
> (def word "Clojure")
> (let [[x & remaining :as all] word]
>   (apply prn [x remaining all]))
> ;= \C (\l \o \j \u \r \e) "Clojure"
> ```
>
> Here `all` is bound to the original structure (String, vector, list, whatever it may be) and `x` is bound to the character `\C`, and `remaining` is the remaining list of characters.

As this demonstrates, `:as` binds the *original*, pre-destructuring value, thus in the example of your loop making `tree` retain its original value. That's not particularly useful when that value already has a name, but is *very* useful when it itself is a return value or otherwise as-yet-unnamed.